# SharePoint List view Options

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Could you guys please let me know about the options:

- Collapsed and
- Expanded

under Create view **>** Group By heading.

Comment: I am so looking forward to the next question

Answer (score 4):

When **Collapsed** is selected:

[image]

Your list will appear like this by default:

[image]

When **Expanded** is selected:

[image]

Your list will appear like this by default:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Collapsed" means that when the users first get to the page, all group sections will be **closed**.

"Expanded" means that when users first get to the page, all group sections will be **open**.